# 1193 - Unknown system variable 'sql_require_primary_key'

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

[image]

when I want to import a database it gave me this error. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 3):

As mysql documentation on [sql_require_primary_key](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sql_require_primary_key) says, this variable was introduced in mysql v8.0.13. So, the target mysql server must be at least this version or later. Otherwise, you need to edit this parameter out of your import file.

Comment: ok I found the solution thanks for your replay